# __init__.py issue in django test

Tags: python, django

I have an issue with running a test in my Django project, using the command python manage.py test. It shows:

```
user:~/workspace/connector$ docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "python manage.py test"
Creating connector_app_run ... done
Found 0 test(s).
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

I was debugging it and I know that it's probably a "**init**.py" file.

If I'm deleting file **init**.py from app.app (I have read somewhere that it can help) then I'm receiving an error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: app.tests.test_secrets (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: app.tests.test_secrets
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/unittest/loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/unittest/loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/app/app/tests/test_secrets.py", line 12, in <module>
    from app.app import secrets
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.app'
```

why did this error occur? Pycharm projects normally see import and what I know from version 3.4 it's not obligatory to put **init**.py into folders to make the package.

This is the github link:

https://github.com/MrHarvvey/connector.git

Can you explain me what I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your first output seems alright, its just that Django didn't find any tests, are you sure that you are following the proper testing [structure](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/overview/#module-django.test) and that your test file is placed right? About the [error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#:~:text=The%20__init__.py,on%20the%20module%20search%20path.)

Comment: Thanks Niko, Yes I was fallowing the documentation. Django should see the tests but it doesn't :(

Comment: Could you share your APP file structure and test code?

Comment: here you have  entire code https://github.com/MrHarvvey/connector.git

Comment: Your `/app/bouncer/test.py` file is empty. Whatever test code you have somewhere, place in that file.

Comment: I'm trying to run app.app.tests.test_secrets there are two tests

Comment: Could you try to move the file out of tests dir into the app folder, rename it tests.py and rerun the test? I've replicated the problem and now facing the same issue, only happens if the test file is inside the test folder.

Comment: Tests directories works inside an APP , but not at project root. Must be related to how Django looks up for tests, I couldn't find any documentation related to this, yet. You can move your test dir into bouncer, and remove the tests.py from that app.

Comment: I have fixed the issue, raising a PR, please review

Comment: It's working. Thanks ! The issue was in import "from import app.app import secrets". Do you know why import app.app doesn't work ? Why there should be import from app import secrets ?  Even my pycharm says this is a mistake https://photos.app.goo.gl/4HL6uXjFu5bv6bhMA and there is no reference to secrets :> but in test it's working, can you explain my why?

Comment: because of your project structure, it has been failing before, in pycharm you need to mark the app directory as the source root, then it will not show that module not found error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as per your project file structure, I changed  `from app.app import secrets` to  `from app import secrets` and then found test cases are also failing, so I fixed them also, you can review the changes here:

https://github.com/MrHarvvey/connector/pull/1

Please let me know you if you wanted something else.